# two projects sharing same user accounts

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have two independent projects / sites which each has it's own database. 
I want to have a common user registration between both. 
Should I created a third database for user accounts?

How should I implement this? I am using PHP Code Igniter (looking at Ion Auth) also that's another problem as the database configuration has to be set in a php config file how would I alternate between both.

Answer (score 2):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

In code:

application/config/database.php:

```
$db["default"]["hostname"] = "localhost";
$db["default"]["username"] = "username";
$db["default"]["password"] = "password";
$db["default"]["database"] = "database";

$db["userdatabase"]["hostname"] = "localhost";
$db["userdatabase"]["username"] = "username";
$db["userdatabase"]["password"] = "password";
$db["userdatabase"]["database"] = "database";
```

In your model:

```
$this->load->database('userdatabase');
// Do user stuff
$this->load->database('default');
```

Comment: That's useful, thank you! I'm still unclear though how to architect this, what if I need to join data from both databases

Comment: Take a look at that link at paragraph **Connecting to Multiple Databases**

Answer (score 1):

Creating a third database will (probably) get you in a mess. Both will have to connect "remotely" and what do you do when both want to update the same record at the same time. Manageable, but will be simpler if you have one as the master, and the other as the slave.

You have three options:

1) Always authenticate against the "Master" database - so even if you are primarily using "Database Slave", you would hop across to "Database Master" for authentication/registration/password change etc,  and then revert to "Slave" for the other operations. You'll need to copy changes to the user and sessions tables on "Master" into "Slave" when they happen, but that's fairly minor and can be built into your models. This is the model I most use and can also hop domains/servers with a bit of playing around.

2) Always authenticate against the local database, and copy changes from either to the other. While it works, you can get in a mess keeping a sessions table alive as you're not sure which one is current.

3) Reverting to the "Master" and "Slave" option, you could set up federated tables (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html). Federated tales support "UPDATE" so when you update the "Slave", you're actually updating the master. But unless your databases are on the same server, and considering your sessions table (assuming you're doing stateless / database handled sessions) will be accessed on every call and frequently updated, I'd avoid this option. Just sayin' that it's an option, though.

Comment: Hey Robbie could you describe more details on how you accomplish 1)

Comment: Sure - are you talking same server / same domain? Or different server / same domains, same server / different domain etc?

Comment: same server / different domain, or different server different domain, either way